# Update table only if value does not exist in a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]I want to update a column (variableA) in a table (myTable) only when

1. There is no dataset with this @variableA in the variableA column
2. There is already a dataset with @variableB in the variableB column and with 'DUMMY' in the variableA column

FYI: Another interface inserts the 'DUMMY' datasets before and I later need to update them with the real variables/numbers.

The code below is already working fine but I am wondering if there is a more "elegant" solution to do this. I want to avoid/change the last line ("SELECT COUNT(*)" etc.)

```
DECLARE @variableA nvarchar(10) = '12345'
DECLARE @variableB nvarchar(10) = '67890'

UPDATE TOP (1) myTable
SET variableA = @variableA,
    timestamp = GETDATE()
WHERE variableB = @variableB
AND variableA = 'DUMMY'
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE variableA = @variableA) = 0
```

Can you please help me to find a smarter solution instead of this last line?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.  For instance, which *row* gets updated?

Comment: Thanks for the adivse. I have added a screenshot with sample data. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would write it like this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET variableA = @variableA,
    timestamp = GETDATE()
WHERE variableB = @variableB
AND variableA = 'DUMMY'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE variableA = @variableA
)
```

First, Using `TOP` without specifing `ORDER BY` is a mistake, since database tables are unsorted by nature, this actually means that you might get unexpected results.

Second, changing the `(select count) > 0` to `exists(select...)` might improve performance (unless the optimizer is smart enough to use the same execution plan for both cases)

Also, for your future questions - **Please** avoid using images to show us sample data and desired results. Use DDL+DML to show sample data, and text to show desired results. If you do that, we can copy your sample data to a test environment and actually test the answers before posting them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks much better! I will keep your advise regarding DDL+DML in mind for the future.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 2):

you can use not exists operator like this

```
not exists (SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE variableA = @variableA)
```

and if it again slow you can set index I_my_Table_variableA by your variableA column and it will be more faster(you can set index by variable because it almost unique and  it will be good index)